# How can I reference the same directory when php file are operating in different folders

Tags: php, foreach, directory

My current folder structure requires php files in different folders and levels of folders. I am using a foreach to grab multiple files and display them inside a template. It works fine if I know where the foreach is going is according to the php using it. However, once a different php file is using the foreach from a different directory it can't find it properly.

Currently:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("media/*.jpg") as $filename){
echo $filename;
?>
```

Files:

```
list1.php
foreach.php
-media/
 image1.jpeg
 image2.jpeg
 image3.jpeg
-posts/
 list2.php
```

Is there a way I can have the foreach.php reference the same folder before looking into media/ for images? Will it work if list1.php & list2.php use the foreach.php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! What you're looking for is a [**root-relative**](https://mor10.com/html-basics-hyperlink-syntax-absolute-relative-and-root-relative/) link, which is a link prefixed with a forward slash:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("/media/*.jpg") as $filename){
echo $filename;
?>
```

> Root-relative hyperlinks are a subset of relative hyperlinks in which all the links are assumed to start from the root folder (domain name) of the site.

The above code looks for any files inside of a `media` folder at root level. This will work regardless of where the file running this code is placed.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Do you mean document root relative.  i.e. prefix with the document root: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/media/*.jpg'`?

Comment: You shouldn't actually need to specify the document root with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, as `glob()` matches a specified pattern. The `/` at the start of the pattern in itself states that it should look in the document root.

Comment: Did you try your code?   Glob reads that as an absolute file path relative to the system root.  Unless Php is jailed.  Or rather this is non-nonsensical, What if I wanted to traverse a part of the file system outside the document root?

Comment: From what I looked into, forward slash does not work within PHP. PHP can see further than html because it is server ran. When tested inside 'list2.php' it does not find the root and looks for 'media/' inside of 'posts/' which does not exist. The alternative is to back out of a file with '../media', but that would break 'list1.php'

Answer (score 0):

If you are having some strange relative path issues.  Try making your paths relative to the file.

e.g.

```
__DIR__ . '/media/*.jpg'
```

OR the document root (note this is a file path):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/media/*.jpg'
```

OR define your own common base path, and make things relative from that:

```
get_my_files_path() . '/media/*.jpg'
```

You could define that as a constant if wanted.  Or as a configurable variable within your code.

From the manual (ini include path):

> include_path string Specifies a list of directories where the require,
>   include, fopen(), file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions
>   look for files.

Not glob.

Relative paths will be relative to your current working directory.

Comment: I have tried 

    `___DIR___ `

and 

   `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/media/*.jpg'`

How would I set the default folder to look in and reference that, when searching from there?

Comment: The magic constant `__DIR__` has two underscores either side not three.

Comment: @Skaldsyn what do you mean by default folder?